# Mousewheel event jquery

Tags: jquery

I currently have a function that overrides the default mousewheel behaviour :

```
$(function() {
      $('body').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
            if (flag) { return false; }
            $current = $('div.current');

           console.log(delta);
           console.log($current);

           if (delta > 0) {
               $prev = $current.prev();

              if ($prev.length) {
                 flag = true;
                $('body').scrollTo($prev, 750, {
                    onAfter : function(){
                        flag = false;
                    }
                });
                $current.removeClass('current');
                $prev.addClass('current');
            }
        } else {
            $next = $current.next();

            if ($next.length) {
                flag = true;
                $('body').scrollTo($next, 750, {
                    onAfter : function(){
                        flag = false;
                    }
                });
                $current.removeClass('current');
                $next.addClass('current');
            }
        }

      event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I use this function to track on what "page" I am  :

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    var sliderObject = $.data( $('#slider-main')[0], 'liquidSlider');
    if (sliderObject.currentTab == 0) {
        home = true;
    }
    else{
        home = false;
    }
}, 500);
```

What I want : I want to override the default behaviour of mousewheel *only* if `home` is set to `true`

In other words, I want to bind the special mousewheel function only if `home` is true.

How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: here's an example http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/ I would just put my event listener code in a function and call it when home is true condition is met, I mean you already did that, just name your first function and call it when needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd do is, inside the listener for mouse wheel event `$.mousewheel` (which I'm not aware [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) supports by the way), have an `if` statement that determines whether `home` is set to true or not and act on it.

In this case:

```
$('body').mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
    if (home === true) {
        // Special behavior
    } else {
        // Default behavior
    }
});
```